# PI Supply, UPS, Pins used

Tags: pi-zero-w, ups

currently I am working with the Raspberry Pi Zero W to build a UPS. Therefore I bought the UPS hat from [Pi Supply](https://uk.pi-supply.com/products/pijuice-zero?_pos=9&_sid=d40c1cc50&_ss=r).

Nevertheless, I have to use 2 Pins for my measurments with the JSN-SR04T-3.0.

Which pins are used for the UPS hat? All? Haven't found any datasheet which offers this information.

Comment: keep looking for the datasheet or examine the UPS hat

Comment: Why not ask Pi Supply?

Comment: @CoderMike I will :D

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING** Though the numbers below match the PIN numbers on the published PDF they **DO NOT** match the numbers normally shown for the Pi. e.g. 5V is on 2 and 4 normally.

Normally I would send you to the great documentation site [pinout.xyz](https://pinout.xyz) for details BUT in this case, the only Pi-Supply board is the [full sized hat](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pijuice) for the Pi-Juice board.

Fortunately they do publish a [schematic on GitHub](https://github.com/PiSupply/PiJuice/blob/master/Documentation/PiJuice_Zero_Schematic.PDF) BUT it is three years old, for version 1.1 of the PiJuiceTop and may not match your board.

Looking on that you can see the board **documented** (i.e. it **may not** match yours) uses:

**See warning above on these numbers**

*Ground* on pins 5,13,19,29,33,10,26,40. (odd given they are all common on the Pi board).

*3v3* on 18

*5v* on 1,3

*ID SCL and ID_SD* on 27, 28 (to tell the Pi it is the UPS card)

*SDA 1 / SCL 1* on 4,6

TBH - I would go back to the suppliers and ask for confirmation this is still valid.

A **QUICK** scan of the [GUI source](https://github.com/PiSupply/PiJuice/blob/master/Software/Source/src/pijuice_gui.py) shows line 34 interrogating address 0x14 on I2C Bus 1 to see if anything is there and that matches the hardware diagram. I'll let you decode the core operating function [PiJuice](https://github.com/PiSupply/PiJuice/blob/e742164d9416fe4f8b45f3e19e8c4e2e13448017/Software/Source/pijuice.py#L1552) if you want more info :-)

Comment: Note I've opened an issue for this numbering https://github.com/PiSupply/PiJuice/issues/576

Comment: Nice. Thank you for the detailed awnser! I stumbled also across the problem that something with the pin mapping is not correct because the board is generally not working correct. (i.e. 90 degree on battery which is obviously false) I will check everthing and awnser you later :D